# How to prove this inequality $x_1+x_2>2ef'(-a)x_1x_2$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

Given that function $f(x)=(a-x)\ln x+2x$ has two different local extrema $x_1, x_2 (x_1<x_2),$

Prove that $x_1+x_2>2ef'(-a)x_1x_2$.

I have proved that the range of a is $(-1,0)$ by taking the first derivative and second derivative of $f(x)$. But I cannot prove the above inequality.

PS: the domain of $f$ is $(0,+\infty)$ for it is a real analysis problem.

Proof for range of $a$:

$f''(x)=\frac{-a-x}{x^2}$, $\therefore -a>0$ i.e. $a<0$ so that $f'(x)$ can have two zeros. $f''(x)>0$ when $x\in (0,-a)$ and $f''(x)<0$ when $x\in (-a,+\infty)$. So $f'(x)$ takes the maximum value when $x=-a$.

$f'(x) = \frac ax -\ln x +1$. It is easy to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} f'(x) = -\infty$ when $a<0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f'(x) = -\infty$. So $f'(-a)=-\ln(-a)>0$, which means $a>-1$.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions for $a$ and domain of $f$?

Comment: @Momo I don't have conditions for $a$ but I think I have proved $a\in (-1,0)$. The domain of $f$ is $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: How did you prove $a>-1$?

Comment: @Momo $f''(x)=\frac{-a-x}{x^2}$, $\therefore -a>0$ i.e. $a<0$ so that $f'(x)$ can have two zeros. $f''(x)>0$ when $x\in (0,-a)$ and $f''(x)<0$ when $x\in (-a,+\infty)$. So $f''(x)$ takes the maximum value when $x=-a$. It is easy to prove $lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} f'(x) = -\infty$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f'(x) = -\infty$. So $f'(-a)=-ln(-a)>0$, which means $a>-1$.

Comment: You mean "$f'(x)$ takes the maximum value"...

Comment: @Momo yes, thank you. sorry I made a writing mistake.